# Do something after a certain time after button clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to have an object disappear from the view after a certain time after a button is tapped.  I'm a little confused with how to get the object to do something a certain after its tapped. I am not sure if I should use a `run loop` or `NSTimer`, and even if I know what to use Im still confused on  what to do to make something happen a certain time after the button is tapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your button pressed method you can use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

And declare method with logic you want to run:

```
-(void) myMethod
{
    //TODO: your logic goes here
}
```

You can even pass parameter to your method if you want (withObject argument).

Answer (score 1):

You can use NStimer Also

```
NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
            target:self
            selector:@selector(afterTapped:)
            userInfo:nil
            repeats:NO];
```

and the create action to be done for **afterTapped**

```
-(void)afterTapped:(id)sender{

      //do something
    }
```